# Having issues with side loading an app on Oculus Go

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, oculusgo

I am trying to side load an app on the Oculus Go to be playable for a friend, but when ever I take it out of developer mode the Unknown Sources tab disappears, and it shows up in the uninstalled as not compatible. I turned Developer mode back on and unknown sources popped back up is there a way he can play it without having to turn on developer mode every time he wants to use it.

Side Information:

Made the app in unity

Side loaded it using ADB install game.apk

Loaded the game up and it ran in developer mode

Answer (score 0):

This is probably an unsigned or self-signed apk file.

You will need to do one of the following:

Either sign the apk with a publicly valid certificate, or

Enable "Unknown Sources" taken from: 
https://support.oculus.com/632287656943461/

1. Open the Oculus app on your PC computer.
2. Select Settings in the left menu.
3. Select the General tab.
4. Next to Unknown Sources, adjust the toggle and then confirm to allow content from unknown sources.

Comment: You have to purchase a code signing certificate from a public Certificate Authority. Then follow the directions here: https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing

Comment: I think that is where the problem I am running into is I cannot find "Personal" section in my oculus go I only have Device, Controller, Power, and about

Comment: Sorry the Oculus Go has split the settings, you must use your PC with the app to do this.

Comment: @ShelbyKing, My apologies, this is the first Android device that I have come across that did not directly implement the complete Google Settings app on the device itself.